# Bad behavior of xepersian with beamer itemize item pause

Tags: beamer, itemize, right-to-left, xepersian

Why `xepersian` breaks item of itemize environment into two pieces and last part of that sticks with previous `pause`! (see attached gif). (Don't worry about font)

Compile specifications: `xelatex + TexLive 2022 + Win 10 + texstudio 4.5.1`

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue!70!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=gray!20}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\usepackage{xepersian}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}
\settextfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Estimation problem}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item  In finance it is a common to consider a parametric model for pricing
            derivatives and then estimate its parameters to the historical market data.
            \item  However, this practice raises some questions about its effectiveness
            and implications.
            \item Our work aims to give answers to these questions and outlines an alternative solution
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a bug in `\pause` cmd appearing in a right to left context (xelatex engine) which can be reproduced with this small example (the package `bidi` is used implicitly by `xepersian` for right to left writing)

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[RTLdocument=on]{bidi}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
one 
\pause   
two 
\pause  
three 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can use `beamer-rl` class to produce your right to left presentation, compilation should be done with lualatex which doesn't produce this problem

```
\documentclass{beamer-rl}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
    
\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue!70!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=gray!20}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\babelprovide[import,main]{persian}
\babelfont{sf}{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Estimation problem}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item  In finance it is a common to consider a parametric model for pricing
            derivatives and then estimate its parameters to the historical market data.
            \item  However, this practice raises some questions about its effectiveness
            and implications.
            \item Our work aims to give answers to these questions and outlines an alternative solution
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: `Option clash for package bidi. .. `. without `[RTLdocument=on]` it compile normally but problem remain.

Answer (score 0):

One trick is break all itemize into single item itemize.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}

\setbeamercolor{block title}{fg=white, bg=blue!70!black}
\setbeamercolor{block body}{fg=black, bg=gray!20}
\setbeamertemplate{blocks}[rounded][shadow=true]

\usepackage{xepersian}
\setsansfont{Times New Roman}
\settextfont{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        \frametitle{Estimation problem}
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]
            \item  In finance it is a common to consider a parametric model for pricing
            derivatives and then estimate its parameters to the historical market data.
        \end{itemize} %<---- added
        \begin{itemize}[<+->]  %<---- added
            \item  However, this practice raises some questions about its effectiveness
            and implications.
            \item Our work aims to give answers to these questions and outlines an alternative solution
        \end{itemize}
    \end{frame}
    
\end{document}
```